# 401 error while using tweepy

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy, http-status-code-401

I am running the below program.But am getting the below error Message.
401 ****
401 ****
(keeps on repeating)

The code(got from some forum) basically tries to connect to Twitter and fetch tweets.
When its ran on ubuntu terminal the 401 error message appear.

```
import sys
import json
import pymongo
import tweepy
consumer_key="XX" ##all the keys and codes have to be strings
consumer_secret="XX"
access_token = "XX"
access_token_secret = "XX"
# This is the listener, resposible for receiving data

class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):

        # Twitter returns data in JSON format - we need to decode it first

        decoded = json.loads(data)



        # Also, we convert UTF-8 to ASCII ignoring all bad characters sent by users

        print '@%s: %s' % (decoded['user']['screen_name'], decoded['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))

        print ''

        return True



    def on_error(self, status):

        print status



if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = StdOutListener()

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)



    print "Showing all new tweets for #programming:"



    # There are different kinds of streams: public stream, user stream, multi-user streams

    # In this example follow #programming tag

    # For more details refer to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis

    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)

    stream.filter(track=['programming'])
```

Comment: You're using your correct consumer/access tokens right? Not just the ones from "some forum" or `"XX"`?

Comment: Am using the correct ones which i got generated from twitter developer site

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how it works..!!!

- Twitter keeps track of the current time.
- If an API request to authenticate comes from a server that claims it is a time that is outside of 15 minutes of Twitter time, it will fail with a 401 error.

Just reset your system's clock according to world clock or let it govern by internet your problem will be solved.

Good luck..!!!

Comment: Hellow how can i do that on Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Go to Settings and Set your clock according to the global time zone.

Comment: IMP: Don't forget to change your timezone in your twitter account and also verify your email! One of these worked for me